# Does the Zebra QLn220 printer have a "Flush" Command?

Tags: printing, zebra-printers, zpl

The ZebraQLn220 has many settings that can be programmatically updated via commands sent it, such as:

```
! U1 setvar "media.sense_mode" "bar"
```

However, sometimes it takes several attempts before that change is "seen"/accepted/applied by the printer. For instance, I have sent the

```
! U1 setvar "power.dtr_power_off" "on"
```

command several times before this one:

```
! U1 getvar "power.dtr_power_off"
```

...will finally respond back with "on" (giving me "off" instead the first several times).

So: Is there a command that can be sent to the QLn220 that tells it to "flush" or "write all changes" or "save changes" or "I really mean it this time" or some such?

### UPDATE

I don't know what firmware is new enough, but this is what the printer tells me about itself as far as "appl" settings go:

```
appl.date : 2/19/2014 
appl.name : V68.19.7Z 
appl.version : 6819 
appl.bootblock : 2.5.9 
appl.link_os_version : 2.0
```

Comment: It's working now - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070743/what-zebra-qln220-settings-do-i-need-to-set-and-to-what-values-to-get-a-sett

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using later firmware you can use JSON to format the commands. In this method the commands will respond immediately with the configured values.

{}{"media.sense_mode":"bar"}

would respond with:

{"media.sense_mode":"bar"}

You can also put multiple requests in one:

{}{"media.sense_mode":"bar",

"power.dtr_power_off":"on"

}

The following knowlege base article has more info - https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO8638&actp=RSS

Comment: How would I know if I am using "later firmware"? Is there a certain value I should look for in the results of a ! U1 getvar "allcv" ?

Comment: Or a "{} {"allconfig":null}" ? 
I guess if the printer responds to this, it's fine? (still waiting in Zebra Setup Utility for a response to that query...)

Comment: The only reference to firmware in the printer settings is:
wlan.firmware_version : 00.00.00.p00
Sending the json "allconfig" command resulted in nothing back from the printer. Maybe the new firmware is for the QLn320 and/or QLn420 on?

Comment: Sending:
{} {"media.sense_mode":"gap"}
to the printer via ZSU returned nothing, so my firmware must be old and decrepit.

Comment: It has been in there for over a year. I can not recall the firmware version. try {}{"allconfig":null} and see if you get a response.

Comment: the firmware version would be in the appl.xxx section. appl.name or appl.verison.

Comment: I'll put the vals in an update, for better formatting than this comment block affords/allows.